# How to transform large numbers to roman in R

Tags: r, largenumber, roman-numerals

I want to transform large numbers (below 10.000) to roman. I know the as.roman function. But that does only go to 3899.

Is it possible to change in the source code in this function and force it to transform the larger numbers - or is it possible to write a new function?

I am running R 3.3.0.

Best, 
Sander.

Comment: What is that reason. The roman2numeric-function goes above 3899.

Comment: 3899 is the largest number that can be written in *standard* roman numerals - but some methods were developed using bars above or between  digits to express larger numbers see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Large_numbers.  But none of these can be expressed as a simple character string

Comment: So the thing is: I can never write "4000" in roman?!

Comment: utils:::.roman2numeric("MMMM")
> 4000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A while back I wrote an integer-to-Roman conversion function in Perl. I just rewrote it in R for this answer. Note that I use the newfangled [`strrep()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strrep.html) function which I believe was only added in 3.3.0.

```
integerToRoman <- function(x) {

    x <- as.integer(x);

    neg <- x<0L;
    x <- abs(x);

    cnt <- integer(length(x));
    res <- rep('',length(x));
    if (any(m <- x==0L)) { res[m] <- 'nulla'; };
    if (any(m <- x>=1000L)) { cnt[m] <- x[m]%/%1000L; x[m] <- x[m]%%1000L; res[m] <- strrep('M',cnt[m]); };
    if (any(m <- x>=900L)) { res[m] <- paste0(res[m],'CM'); x[m] <- x[m]-900L; };
    if (any(m <- x>=500L)) { res[m] <- paste0(res[m],'D'); x[m] <- x[m]-500L; };
    if (any(m <- x>=400L)) { res[m] <- paste0(res[m],'CD'); x[m] <- x[m]-400L; };
    if (any(m <- x>=100L)) { cnt[m] <- x[m]%/%100L; x[m] <- x[m]%%100L; res[m] <- paste0(res[m],strrep('C',cnt[m])); };
    if (any(m <- x>=90L)) { res[m] <- paste0(res[m],'XC'); x[m] <- x[m]-90L; };
    if (any(m <- x>=50L)) { res[m] <- paste0(res[m],'L'); x[m] <- x[m]-50L; };
    if (any(m <- x>=40L)) { res[m] <- paste0(res[m],'XL'); x[m] <- x[m]-40L; };
    if (any(m <- x>=10L)) { cnt[m] <- x[m]%/%10L; x[m] <- x[m]%%10L; res[m] <- paste0(res[m],strrep('X',cnt[m])); };
    if (any(m <- x>=9L)) { res[m] <- paste0(res[m],'IX'); x[m] <- x[m]-9L; };
    if (any(m <- x>=5L)) { res[m] <- paste0(res[m],'V'); x[m] <- x[m]-5L; };
    if (any(m <- x>=4L)) { res[m] <- paste0(res[m],'IV'); x[m] <- x[m]-4L; };
    if (any(m <- x>=1L)) res[m] <- paste0(res[m],strrep('I',x[m]));

    if (any(neg)) res[neg] <- paste0('-',res[neg]);

    res;

}; ## end integerToRoman()
```

Demo:

```
set.seed(319072L); data.frame(int=x <- sample(seq(0L,5e3L),20L),roman=integerToRoman(x));
##     int          roman
## 1   614          DCXIV
## 2  4825    MMMMDCCCXXV
## 3     6             VI
## 4  4721     MMMMDCCXXI
## 5     9             IX
## 6  3333   MMMCCCXXXIII
## 7  2114         MMCXIV
## 8  4861    MMMMDCCCLXI
## 9  1042          MXLII
## 10 3609        MMMDCIX
## 11  417         CDXVII
## 12  241          CCXLI
## 13    3            III
## 14 4952      MMMMCMLII
## 15 1370        MCCCLXX
## 16 1789     MDCCLXXXIX
## 17 3730      MMMDCCXXX
## 18 2275       MMCCLXXV
## 19 1139        MCXXXIX
## 20 4898 MMMMDCCCXCVIII
```