# Convert numeric to roman in R

Tags: r, roman-numerals

Related: [Convert roman numerals to numbers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116763/convert-roman-numerals-to-numbers-in-r)

In the above question, an answer states that there is a function `utils:::.roman2numeric()` to convert roman to numeric. I also found out that there is a similar function to convert numeric to roman: `utils:::.numeric2roman()`. Unfortunately it does not work for some numbers, why?

E.g. `3978`, `3985` produces `NA`

This is similar to how `as.roman()` doesn't work for some roman numbers converting to numerics. E.g. `MMMCMXI` gives `NA` instead of `3911`.

Is there another function that works for numeric to roman 100% of the time? (Best if it's builtin)

**Bonus**: another function that works, other than `utils:::.roman2numeric()`, for roman to numeric. (`as.roman()` does not work as explained earlier).

Answer (score 5):

From the help page `?utils::as.roman`:

> Only numbers between 1 and 3899 have a unique representation as roman numbers, and hence others result in as.roman(NA).

[Here is a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889619/how-to-transform-large-numbers-to-roman-in-r) that claims to convert larger numeric values to Roman.

For the other direction you could try [gtools::roman2int](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtools/versions/3.9.4/topics/roman2int).

Comment: Do you know of any builtin function that goes over 3899? Thanks

Comment: I don't believe there's a "builtin" (_i.e._ base R) function other than what's discussed here already.